# Objective C Database SQLite TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I am new to Objective C and I would like to know if anyone can help me?

**TableView Controller**

I am trying to create a TableView Controller with a Navigational Controller

On my TableView Controller I would like to display stored information that a user has input into it (database).

**Example:**

Day: Monday

Classroom: A11

Starting Time: 10:00

Ending Time: 14:00

**Navigational Controller**

The navigational controller will have a "add" button on the right side where it seagues them to a new view controller where the user can add information for the above example.

Comment: your question not clear what you want store data in database or retrieve data from database?

Comment: @DixitAkabari I would need to know both because i am very new to database